Power BI table shows one of the column values in the total instead of the column sum
I have this table in Power BI that instead of showing the total in Total Assets column it shows one of the values. In this example, instead of showing the total, it shows the value of the second row 1,464.

The Total Assets column is calculated with a DAX measure, like so:
Bank Balance Total Assets = 
VAR TargetDate = [Latest Date Call Report] -- this returns the date to report
RETURN
 CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK(VALUES(balance_sheet[TotalAssets]),1),
    balance_sheet[RPT_DATE] = TargetDate
) / 1000 

The Total Assets column represents the Total Assets that a bank has in its balance sheet on a specific date. The table shows all the banks in a specific group on a specific date (filtered in the context) .


Update
I uploaded a sample file that replicates the problem here: https://sofiana.ai/error_replicate.pbix

Can you provide some dummy data with the current input and the expected one ? including your model ?

@AmiraBedhiafi please see update, you can download the pbix file that replicates the problem

you can try this to get the total value.
measure = SUMX(values([Fed RRSD]),Bank Balance Total Assets)


measure1 =sum(Asset)
measuure2 = SUMX(values([Fed RRSD]),measure1)


How can I use the measure in the total? The total in the table is calculated automatically by Power BI, not with a measure

updated the answer, pls have a try

Not sure how to implement these measures
